# Member Temporary Password

Tags: members, registration

Is it possible in EE 2.6.1 to have a super-admin create a member of another group, and have the system send a temporary password, and then have the user login to the front-end with that temporary password. These members will never have access to the control panel. Are there any good 3rd party modules that would accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You should try [MX Auto Password](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-notify-control) and [MX Notify Control](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-notify-control)